# How to get all posts from each user?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, count

I have the table `users` with information about every user. Then the table `posts` with information about articles and finally the table `user_posts`, which contains following columns:

```
user_id
post_id
...
```

I am trying to get the chart of users with the highest count of posts. I made this query:

> SELECT u.id as uid, u.name as uname,
>          count(up.id) as up_count 
>   FROM users as u JOIN user_posts as up ON up.user_id = u.id ORDER BY vcount DESC LIMIT 25

This query returns me only one user and the total count of all rows in the table `user_posts`.

What am I doing wrong? I need to get the list of 25 users sorted by the count of articles that published each user.

Thank you in advance

Comment: try left join in place of join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query needs to have `GROUP BY` clause because you have used `COUNT()` function.

```
SELECT   u.id as uid, 
         u.name as uname, 
         count(up.id) as up_count 
FROM     users as u 
           LEFT JOIN user_posts as up  
              ON up.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY u.id, u.name
ORDER BY up_count DESC LIMIT 25
```

You must have grouped them by `ID` otherwise you'll single total count result for all records. One more thing, use `LEFT JOIN` so even users with no post still will be visible in you result with the score of `0`.

Comment: @James it think the OP means `up_count`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    u.id as uid, u.name as uname, count(up.id) as up_count 
FROM users as u 
    JOIN user_posts as up ON up.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY 
    u.id, u.name
ORDER BY 
    vcount 
DESC LIMIT 25
```